# Include assets in dashboard created by an .exe via PyInstaller()

Tags: python, pyinstaller, plotly-dash

I created a dashboard via `plotly dash`. This dashboard will be used on a single machine in a lab. Hence, I didn't host it on a server or the like but created an .exe with `PyInstaller()`. When executed, a window will open with these lines:

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8054/

 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

Then, one simply has to enter the above URL/IP and the dashboard opens up. This works fine except of the situation that the `.css` files in the assets folder are apparently ignored somewhere through the process.
How do I ensure to include them?

Answer (score 1):

Its not very clear but im assuming you have some custom css files.

Pyinstaller .exe assets path are handled just the way you would expect when executing a script - it is relative unless you provide a full path.

I had a game written in pygame, and we just had an `assets` folder, which was bundeled alongside the .exe.

I would check your paths in the code first, because theres no reason they will be ignored

Comment: Thank you, but dash is importing the folder assets automatically, I do not have to specify this in code somewhere. That's probably why PyInstaller is ignoring this.

Comment: worth checking, write here how it goes

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to specify the assets folder through dash already, e.g.:

```
app = dash.Dash(
                __name__
                , server = server
                , title='Dashboard'
                , external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets
                , assets_folder = 'assets'
                )
```